# input is displayed twice in the console of firefox developer edition

Tags: firefox, console

I downloaded Firefox Developer Edition latest version and opened its Dev Tools Tab to use its console . All is right and good except that when I write , in the left side a JavaScript and click on the run button , the script is displayed again along with the result like in the following photo:

[image]

I do not want the script or input to be displayed twice . I would like to see only the result in the right side . I read the documentation in this web page :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools

and looked in this webpage :

https://discourse.mozilla.org/c/devtools/213?utm_source=devtools/213&utm_medium=tabbar-menu

along with the similar questions section in

stackoverflow.com

However , I could not find a solution to my problem .

Answer (score 1):

The output window outputs the following:

- An echo of the script
- Messages

  - Errors
  - Warnings
  - Logs
  - Info
  - Debug

Unchecking any of the Message types in the task pane will not remove the echo of the script since technically it is not an output message. The same goes for filtering, since filtering is only applied to messages in the output.

This functionality looks like it is by-design and I am sure there might be a reason why it was built in this way, but if it is an issue for you I think you can raise it in their community forums:

https://discourse.mozilla.org/